# Impossible to delete blank line in generated word with template

Tags: ms-word, acceleo, m2doc

I'm currently using m2doc for my Capella project and when I launch the generatio of the docuement with the template that I have created some lines in my tables are empty and they are not deleted.
Example :

test | test | test

```
 |      |
```

file | file | file

I'm currently using Acceleo in my template to retrieve the information in my Capella diagrams. But I don't know how to delete this empty lines in the table which are useless for me. 
Example of my code :

{ m:if ports.name.contains('LOC')}

So I need your help to delete this empty lines in my table.

Thank you.

Regards,

Marc

Answer (score 0):

If you insert your table using asTable*() from [Sirius services](https://www.m2doc.org/ref-doc/nightly/m2doc_service_m2docsiriusservices.html), the table is an instance of the Java type MTable.
You can write a Java service that take a MTable as parameter and check for MRow without any MCell in it. If the MRaw is empty remove it from the table and return the table.